# PHP - Get base64 in data

Tags: php, base64

How can I get the base64 value properly in PHP from a submitted data?

The data being passed on is

```
data:image/png;base64,LongBase64ValueHereOfAnImage
```

Right now, I can only get it by

```
$data = $_POST['image'];
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list($data) = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
```

Is there a proper way to get the base64 value?

Comment: If you just want the data, you could also do [`[$junk, $data] = explode('base64,', $string)`](https://3v4l.org/USZsc)  or if you wanted the mime-type info and the data use [`preg_match('/^data:(\w+\/.+);base64,(.+)$/', $string, $matches);`](https://3v4l.org/88nLS); There are tons of ways to properly accomplish retrieving the base64 value from an data URI scheme, one of which is your method.

Comment: Another method to retrieve just the base64 encoded strng would be to use [`substr($string, stripos($string, 'base64,')+7);`](https://3v4l.org/scQcd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done in one line with regex

```
$data = $_POST['image'];
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: uploading image code.

```
if (count($_FILES) > 0) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');
        $imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO upload(image) VALUES('$imgData')";
        $current_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysqli_error($conn));
        if (isset($current_id)) {
            echo 'done';
        }
    }
}
```

And then get data using base64

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = 113";
$sth = $conn->query($sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($result['image']) . '"/>';
```

Comment: The OP only wants the base64 encoded string from the HTML image data string. ie. removing `data:image/png;base64,` from the string.